# Can I overfeed my kitten?

Tags: cats, feeding

I got a new kitten and bought a food dispenser that seems to simply let the food out infinitely as the kitten eats.

Will the kitten stop eating when it has had a healthy amount?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never heard of a *kitten* with a weight problem. They tend to get plenty of exercise through play, and don't eat more than they need. So I wouldn't worry about the kitten eating too much.

Weight problems typically occur when the cat grows older and becomes less active.

Answer (score 1):

Kittens require more food than adult cats so it's probably ok that he's eating a lot.

Typically, kittens should be fed three times a day as opposed to the two times/day of their adult counterparts.